# Pandas: read file with special characters in a column

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas

In the data that I have, some feature values are `?`. How do I replace them with `NA`?

**EDIT**

The code and output is as below:

```
df = pd.read_csv("cca-census-income.csv", header = None)

df.replace('?', np.nan, inplace=True)

df.ix[0,]

23                Other relative of householder
24                                      1700.09
25                                            ?
26                                            ?
27                                            ?
28             Not in universe under 1 year old
29                                            ?
30                                            0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add parameter `na_values='?'` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import io


temp=u"""Date Time,a
2010-01-27 16:00:00,?
2010-01-27 16:10:00,2.2
2010-01-27 16:30:00,1.7"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp),na_values='?')
print (df)
             Date Time    a
0  2010-01-27 16:00:00  NaN
1  2010-01-27 16:10:00  2.2
2  2010-01-27 16:30:00  1.7
```

EDIT:

Thank you ['shivsn'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38233046/pandas-read-file-with-special-characters-in-a-column#comment63888424_38233073) for suggestion add `skipinitialspace=True`:

```
temp=u"""Date Time,a
 ? , ?
? ,?
2010-01-27 16:30:00,1.7"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp),na_values=['?', '? '], skipinitialspace =True)
print (df)
             Date Time    a
0                  NaN  NaN
1                  NaN  NaN
2  2010-01-27 16:30:00  1.7
```

EDIT1 by file:

It looks like there is only `space` before `?`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('census-income.data', 
                 header = None, 
                 na_values=['?'], 
                 skipinitialspace =True)
print (df)
```

Comment: I tried this but it does not work. `df = pd.read_csv("train.csv", header = None, na_values='?')` The output is of `df.ix[0,]` still shows `?`

Comment: Is there `?` only? Maybe there is some space.

Comment: try adding `skipintialspace=True`.

Comment: @jezrael Not that I can see. The data is from here https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Census-Income+%28KDD%29

Answer (score 1):

after reading the file use [replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) :

```
df.repalce('.?',np.nan,inplace=True,regex=True)
```

Comment: This is not working as well. I have just provided the code and output.